# Is it possible to check Age Limit progress when applied to Exchange 2013 Public Folders?

Tags: exchange-2013, public-folders

We have turned on custom Age Limits for 2 separate Public Folders (and subfolders) in our Exchange 2013 environment. Although it seems to be working in part, A lot of mails I'd expect to be gone are still available in the Public Folder.

My first thought was that the propagation of Age Limit must not be done yet, and it is still checking mails for their age and deleting if necessary.

Is there a way to follow the status of the Age Limit propagation to Public Folders? I'd like to know when it is done so I can decide whether the settings work as expected.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike retention policy that it will display expired date and retention day, it will **not** display the expire information on public folder with **Age limit** settings.

Another is that we can use [Get-PublicFolderItemStatistics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997949%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) to check the last modification time or list the expiring item by **LastModificationTime**.